# How can we apply the definition?

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Show that $$g(x, y)=ye^x+\sin x+(xy)^4$$ is continuous.

The definition is:

$f : A \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous at $x_0 \in A$ iff $\forall \epsilon \exists \delta:$ 
$$\text{ if } x \in A, ||x-x_0||<\delta \Rightarrow ||f(x)-f(x_0)||<\epsilon$$

Could you give me some hints how we could apply it in this case??

**EDIT:**

$g$ is the sum of the functions $ye^x$, $\sin x$ and $(xy)^4$.

So to show that $g$ is continuous, it suffices to show that each of them is continuous.

The first one is continuous as the product of the continuous functions $y$ and $e^x$.

The second one is continuous.

The third one is the composition of the function $(x, y, z) \mapsto z^4$ with the product $x \cdot y$, so it is continuous.

So, we conclude that $g$ is continuous.

Is this correct?? Is the formulation correct?? Could I improve something??

Comment: I'm not sure what you are permitted to use.  First show that the sum of continuous functions is continuous.  Then, show that the product of continuous functions is continuous.  That should suffice.  You can use the property that the exponential function is convex and you can use analogous properties for the sine function in sub-domains.   Finally, you can use the equivalence between $||\vec x-  \vec x_o||=\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}<\delta$ in $R^2$ and $|x-x_0|<\delta'$ and $|y-y_0|<\delta'$.

Comment: I have edited my initial post... Could you take a look at it?? @Dr.MV

Comment: Are you expected to show the continuity of the individual terms?  Or are you permitted to assume that they are continuous?  Can you assume that sums and products of continuous functions are continuous?

Comment: There is a thereom that says that the sum, the product and the composition of two continuous functions  is continuous. @Dr.MV

Comment: There is the following example in my book: 
$$$$ Let $f(x, y, z)=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{30}+\sin z^3$. Show that $f$ is continuous. 
$$$$
We can write $f$ as a sum of the two functions $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{30}$ and $\sin z^3$, so it suffices to show that  each of them is continuous. The first one is the composition of $(x, y, z) \rightarrow (x^2+y^2+z^2)$ with $u \rightarrow u^{30}$, and the second one is the composition of $(x, y, z) \rightarrow z^3$ with $u \rightarrow \sin u$, and the continuity follows from the theorem. @Dr.MV

Comment: Then, I think you're OK to proceed analogously.

Comment: So, is it the way I formulated it correct?? Could I improve something?? @Dr.MV

Comment: I think you have it.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that both the sum and the product of continuous functions are also continuous. So if you can show that each of the parts is, you have an easy result.
If a part contains both an x and y part, think about what happens if you make one of them constant and evaluate in terms of the other. Is it continuous in both cases? Then there's the result you want (that is: continuous for "x constant, y variable" + continuous for "x variable, y constant" = continuous for "x and y variable").
You can use your definition to make it formal, by considering two different delta and epsilon, one of corresponding to x and y.

Comment: I have edited my initial post... Could you take a look at it?? @Nij

Comment: As per the comments with Dr. MV above.